# Astro Network work only with run dev || not work with astro preview - node adapter

Tags: astrojs

In this way I can run astro in dev mode with specific network and port.

```
 npm run dev -- --host --port=3011
```

But how to run Astro production?   Im working before with Nextjs, and in Nextjs i can do this with: npm run start, but looks like this way astro also in running in dev mode.

i try

```
npx astro preview -- --host --port=3011
```

But in this way  astro is loaded in port 4321, so looks like not read called port in this way.

@update

```
I try also in config file:
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3011,
    host: true,
  },
  output: "server",
  integrations: [
    tailwind({
      config: {
        applyBaseStyles: false,
      },
    }),
    svelte(),
  ],
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone",
  }),
});
```

Now when I try: npx astro preview then run on port 3011 but wihout network true (so website is only accessable from localhost).

When I run

```
 npm run dev -- --host --port=3011
```

Then working with port and network.

SSH:

```
[d9yfcre2@server xxxxx]$ npm run dev

> second-singularity@0.0.1 dev
> astro dev


 astro  v4.2.8 ready in 521 ms

┃ Local    http://localhost:3011/
┃ Network  http://public_ip:3011/

22:34:11 watching for file changes...
```

Dev mode working and network working (proxy pass domain is also working).
Now with preview:

```
[d9yfcre2@server xxxx]$ npx astro preview
22:35:13 [@astrojs/node] Server listening on http://localhost:3011
```

Network not working. Only curl localhost:3011 from root working, . Maybe I should edit anything in node adapter? I use ngnix + node 18